# Problem with SQLBindParameter on IN/OUT parameter

Tags: c++, odbc

I have the following parameter being bound for calling a SQL procedure:

```
TCHAR str[41];
SQLINTEGER cb;
SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, SQL_C_TCHAR, SQL_C_TCHAR, 40, 0, str, 0, &cb);
```

When I loop through str after calling the query I can see the result is there, but it's not quite right:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss<<"{";
for(int i=0;i<41;++i)
{
    ss<<(int)str[i];
    if(i<40)ss<<',';
}
ss<<"}"<<endl<<"{";
for(int i=0;i<41;++i)
{
    if(str[i])
        ss<<"'"<<str[i]<<"'";
    else
        ss<<"null";
    if(i<40)ss<<',';
}
ss<<"}"<<endl;
cout<<ss.str();
```

{53,55,56,49,53,**32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32**,0}
{'5','7','8','1','5',**' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '**,null}

For whatever reason, str is being padded with spaces. I know the SQL procedure is actually returning "57815" from testing it in isolation. Any ideas what's going on and how to resolve it?
The cb value is set to 40 after the SQL call is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SQL database field is of type CHAR, it will be space padded (and if it isn't a CHAR, what type is it?). This is expected behaviour. If it isn't are you sure that SQL_C_TCHAR is the type you really want - it isn't listed on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713346%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: If it's space-padded how am I supposed to know the correct value... the DB row could in come cases contain trailing spaces for instance. In my usage it _is_ safe to assume trailing spaces can be discarded but there must be general solution?

Comment: @John You still haven't said what the type of the SQL field is in the database. If the field is of type CHAR then basically it shouldn't be - it should be a VARCHAR.

Comment: Aha. I see what you mean. VARCHAR does indeed fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use VARCHAR instead of CHAR, use SQL_VARCHAR as SQL type of your argument